# Set different columnwidth for one Multicolumn Listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, listbox

I'm looking for a way to set different column width on my multicolumn listbox. The first one shall be 0 so it would be hidden, the second one 15, the third one 85, and so on

My goal is to create a listbox referencing products from where my user could click to select such product and then perform different actions on said product using buttons

The listbox gets his data from a MySQL DB

Comment: Suggest using a ListView instead. Or DataGridView.

Comment: I'm afraid a multicolumn `ListBox` doesn't work the way you think it does.  It's not like you have a single item on a row and then parts of it displayed in each column.  It's still just a single list of items.  The multicolumn part comes in when you get enough items to reach the bottom of the control.  By default, the next item is just added to the bottom of the list and a scrollbar is displayed but, in a multicolumn `ListBox`, the next item wraps to another column. If you're getting data from a database, use a `DataGridView`.  That's what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a class to store you data. You can add as many properties as you need to match the fields in you database table. I added a custom constructor to simplify setting properties when you create a new product. I have overridden .ToString because a listbox calls .ToString on the objects being added.

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property Price As Decimal
    Public Sub New(Name As String, ProductPrice As Decimal)
        ProductName = Name
        Price = ProductPrice
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return ProductName
    End Function
End Class
```

Create a Form level list varaible to hold a list of your Product data.
Retrieve the data and store each record in the list.

```
Private lstProduct As New List(Of Product)
Private Sub GetData()
    Using cn As New MySqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select * From Products;", cn)
            cn.Open()
            Using dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                While dr.Read
                    Dim p As New Product(dr.GetString(0), dr.GetDecimal(1))
                    lstProduct.Add(p)
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

After you get the data you can use the list as a .DataSource for the ListBox.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GetData()
    ListBox2.DataSource = lstProduct
End Sub
```

Now you have all the properties of the product available in the ListBox.

```
Private Sub ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim p As Product = DirectCast(ListBox2.SelectedItem, Product)
    Dim ProductPrice As Decimal = p.Price
    Debug.Print(ProductPrice.ToString)
End Sub
```